# How can get an express webservice from a methode selenium with javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, express, web-services, selenium-webdriver

I did a simple method using selenium with JavaScript I would like to launch this method when I call a simple web service created by express
this is the method of selenium :

```
async function example()
{
    try{
        let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("firefox").build();
        await driver.get("https://accounts****.com/login")
        await driver.manage().window().setRect(814, 705)
        await driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("*******")
        await driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("*****",Key.RETURN)firefox
    }catch(error){
        console.log(">>>>error: "+error)
    }
}
```

I tried this web service but doesn't work with me :

```
server.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.send(example())
})
```

So the idea is when I call this web service http://localhost:3000/login. I would like to launch the method of selenium, can you help please!

Comment: Just want clarification, you want to Run the example code on a GET request to /login, what info do you want to return to the client that called the request?

Comment: @EthanSnow when I run the get request /login I wanna just execute the method example()

Answer (score 0):

So this is quite simple if all you want to do is run a function by an express call.

```js
server.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(202) // This status code means the request was Accepted, but might not be handled yet, or might not even succeed.
  example()
})
```

Here we tell the client that the request is being handled, then run the function `example`.

Do note however that this will not tell the client calling the request any info about what happens afterwards, so we respond with `202:Accepted` which you can find more info about What that means and Why we use it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, however I tested it but doesn't launch the method example, because the method example() expected to launch a new page's firefox

Comment: Another question for clarity, What exactly are you attempting to achieve?; As your current code will login to a site, then do nothing.

Comment: Yes  exactly do you have an idea how to fix that

Comment: Once again, What `Exactly` are you expecting to happen? The problem is unclear as you have not specified any end result. You state you want to launch selenium, which calling example() does sucessfully if its not throwing an error.

Comment: What expecting to happen when I call my web service is is to launch a new browser Firefox and enter the website https://accounts****.com/login then enter the login and password then click on ENTER button

Comment: I think maybe I see whats happening, Is your intended purpose to Test parts of a website? Selenium is used for automated testing of website, and does not open a new browser. If you are attempting to open a new browser on the client and login to a website, that is not possible for security reasons.